# Why do null.equals(null) do not throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

null.equals(null) does not throw NullPointerException in my case. Not able to understand. In the following code snippet in the else if condition there is a chance where basePartNumber and partNumber can be null. When the control comes there and i investigate in eclipse i see a NullPointerExcption. But it does not throw the exception and the code continues with next iteration .Can someone explain

```
String basePartnumber = null;
for(Row detailRow:detailRows){
String partNumber = AscendRowUtil.getString(detailRow, ASNConstants.BUYER_PART_NUMBER);
                if(basePartnumber == null){
                    basePartnumber = partNumber;
                } else if(!basePartnumber.equals(partNumber)){
                    validationResult.addMessage(ASNI18nMessageKeys.ERROR_ASN_CANNOT_HAVE_DIFFERENT_PARTNUMBER_ITEMS);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: if `basePartnumber` is null, then `else` block will not be executed. So no NPE

Comment: else will be executed only when basePartnumber is not null, if you want both sattements to get executed, you can have !basePartnumber.equals(partNumber

Comment: How `basePartnumber` can be null in the else if part? If that's null, it will fall into if part.

Comment: that statement in one more if not in if else

Comment: if(basePartnumber == null){
                    basePartnumber = partNumber;
                }if(!basePartnumber.equals(partNumber)){
                    validationResult.addMessage(ASNI18nMessageKeys.ERROR_ASN_CANNOT_HAVE_DIFFERENT_PARTNUMBER_ITEMS);
                    break;
                }

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger, what do you see.  If you don't understand code which some one has written, this is the first thing you should do.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at your code. The `else` part is never executed since `basePartnumer == null` is always true because `basePartnumber = null`.

```
String basePartnumber = null;
...
if(basePartnumber == null){
    basePartnumber = partNumber;
} else if(!basePartnumber.equals(partNumber)){
```

Comment: This is often the whole point of writing an `if(basePartnumber == null){` block before the `equals` comparison. +1

Answer (score 0):

basePartnumber will never be null in your else-if condition, because if it's null the code above is executet. So it will never reach that point. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
                if(basePartnumber == null){ // 1
                    basePartnumber = partNumber;
                } else if(!basePartnumber.equals(partNumber)){ // 2
                    validationResult.addMessage(ASNI18nMessageKeys.ERROR_ASN_CANNOT_HAVE_DIFFERENT_PARTNUMBER_ITEMS);
                    break;
                }
```

In your example, line 1 will be true for any null, because you are using else-if, which is a way of saying

```
if(basePartnumber ==null){
  // code here
}else {
  if (!basePartnumber .equals(partNumber)){
    // code here
  }
}
```

your line

```
  !basePartnumber.equals(partNumber)
```

is null safe (basePartnumber is never null in line 2).